# Force gcc to compile 32 bit programs on 64 bit platform

Tags: linux, gcc, 32-bit, x86-64

I've got a proprietary program that I'm trying to use on a 64 bit system.

When I launch the setup it works ok, but after it tries to update itself and compile some modules and it fails to load them.

I'm suspecting it's because it's using gcc and gcc tries to compile them for a 64 bit system and therefore this program cannot use these modules.

Is there any way (some environmental variables or something like that) to force gcc to do everything for a 32 bit platform. Would a 32 bit chroot work?

Comment: Try posting to stackoverflow. You'll probably get a good response there

Comment: The problem is with installing the program, not writing it @Nathan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit linux machine with gcc/cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to make GCC use the `-m32` flag.

You could try writing a simple shell script to your `$PATH` and call it gcc (make sure you don't overwrite the original gcc, and make sure the new script comes earlier in `$PATH`, and that it uses the full path to GCC.

I think the code you need is just something like `/bin/gcc -m32 $*` depending on your shell (the `$*` is there to include all arguments, although it might be something else – very important!)

Comment: You'll also need the 32bit C library, as well as 32 bit versions of whatever external libraries the program links against in some cases.

Comment: Indeed. Standard libraries: C: `apt-get install gcc-multilib`; C++: `apt-get install g++-multilib`.

Answer (score 52):

You may get a 32-bit binary by applying Alan Pearce's method, but you may also get errors as follows:

```
fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
```

If this is the case and if you have apt-get, just install gcc-multilib

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Comment: For C++ projects, `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib`.

Answer (score 10):

For any code that you compile directly using `gcc`/`g++`, you will need to add `-m32` option to the compilation command line, simply edit your `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables in your `Makefile`.

For any 3rd party code you might be using you must make sure when you build it to configure it for cross compilation. Run `./configure --help` and see which option are available. In most cases you can provide your `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables to the configure script. You also might need to add `--build` and `--host` to the configure script so you end up with something like

```
./configure CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

If compilation fails this probably means that you need to install some 32 bit development packages on your 64 bit machine