# 32 bits vs 64 bits compiling

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly

I am trying to build libgloss but when I run make, I get a serie of message, related to a my 64 bits osx :

```
/libgloss/i386/cygmon-crt0.S:76:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
```

when I look a this file I get `movl` and `pushl` 32 bits sequences. But I don't find the right the right option to add to `make` in order to compile as 32 bits. Someone has an idea ? I googled it and I found some options but it didn't work (such like `--32`...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501878/force-gcc-to-compile-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-platform

Comment: @mikyra I tried make -m32, but I get make: invalid option -- 3

Comment: Make won't know it, as it's not an option to make but to gcc. Most probably setting CFLAGS=-m32 is what you want to do.

Comment: @mikyra, it seemed to work, but half a way. I get now this message : libgloss/libnosys/chown.c:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘(’ token, libgloss/libnosys/chown.c:7:22: error: _syslist.h: No such file or directory... Do you have an idea ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not - I have even never heard of libgloss until today.

Comment: Let's step back a second: Why are you trying to compile libgloss for Mac OS X? A full toolchain is already available for the platform.