# -m32 option doesn't work with gcc but works with g++

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I was trying to compile an application for 32 bit target on x86_64 ubuntu 12.04 machine.
I installed the required packages using

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-i386 libc6-dev-i386
```

The first command works generating the 32 bit version. However, the second command errors out

```
1. g++ -m32 hello.c 

2. gcc -m32 hello.c
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

Could anyone explain to me why gcc fails to work. Am I missing some libraries?

Thanks!

---

---

Comment: Related: [Force gcc to compile 32 bit programs on 64 bit platform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3501878) is the canonical Q&A about needing `gcc-multilib` for stuff to work.  This Q&A seems to be about version mismatches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I upgraded my g++ to 4.8 and g++ -m32 stopped working too. Installing g++-4.8-multilib made -m32 option work with both gcc and g++.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this package of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Also confirm that you are using `gcc multilib` with `gcc -v`. If not set path accordingly or re-install `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: I do have it installed. Apologies for not mentioning it before.

Comment: @SArora, can you try: gcc -m32 -L/usr/lib32 -o hello hello.c

Comment: Yeah. I tried that before. It doesn't work. I do have crt1.o and libgcc_s.so.1 in /usr/lib32. I wonder if it looking for something else.

Comment: I think you have $PATH issue, you are not using gcc multilib, can you verify gcc -v? Set path accordingly to gcc multilib binary.

Comment: Installing g++-4.8-multilib helped me resolve the issue.
Thanks!

Comment: @SArora, great! You can choose answer if it worked for you, so question will be closed.

Comment: At the time perhaps a good answer, but in 2017 this answer is seriously outdated.