# Assembly and C compiler

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I state that I am a beginner.I wrote a small program, max.c

```
int max(int a,int b){
  if(a > b) return a;
  return b;
}
```

I compiled with:

```
gcc -m32 -S max.c
```

to generate the IA32 assembly program. Then, I created a small main trial to test the operation of the program, main-max.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int a,int b);
int main(){
  printf("%d\n",max(3,-5));
  printf("%d\n",max(3,5));
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled and passing the assembly code of the program previously compiled:

```
gcc -m32 main-max.c max.s -o max
```

gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: saltato /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a incompatible durante la ricerca di 
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: saltato /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so incompatible durante la ricerca 
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

you know help me?

Comment: Please write the error messages in English.

Comment: Please do `export LANG=C` before running compiler so we can read your errors in English

Comment: No idea if this will work, but try changing the order, that is: `gcc -m32 max.s main-max.c -o max`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103826/m32-option-doesnt-work-with-gcc-but-works-with-g

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit system? Have you installed the multilib packages for GCC?

Comment: This is the error:
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s

Comment: The linker doesn't find  valid libraries: libgcc.a and libgcc_s.so

Comment: See the answer of the user @Silverstorm in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498237/compile-program-for-32bit-on-64bit-linux-os-causes-fatal-error

Comment: I installed the libraries, as you suggested, but the error remains @SergioFormiggini

Comment: @Balboa. Try to see if the libraries the linker searches are in the correct path. You may do this at the system pront: cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu then, at the system prompt: find . -iname " * gcc * " (without the spaces insides the ""). You should see something like this: ./4.8/libgcc.a
./4.8/libgcc_eh.a
./4.8/include/stdint-gcc.h
./4.8/x32/libgcc.a
./4.8/x32/libgcc_eh.a
./4.8/x32/libgcc_s.so
./4.8/32/libgcc.a
./4.8/32/libgcc_eh.a
./4.8/32/libgcc_s.so
./4.8/libgcc_s.so
./4.8/libgcc_s_x32.so
./4.8/libgcc_s_32.so

Comment: I checked all the directories that you wrote: there are all except  ./4.8/32/libgcc.a ./4.8/32/libgcc_eh.a ./4.8/32/libgcc_s.so ./4.8/libgcc_s_32.so @SergioFormiggini

Comment: @Balboa. The compiler is saying to you that the libraries are not in the format it expects. I think should be a good idea that you uninstall and re-install such a libraries. (On my Linux 64 bits (Ubuntu 14.10) the code is compiled without problems)

Comment: could you show me how to do?My problem could not be because I'm working on virtual machine? @SergioFormiggini

Comment: i solved! I installed the missing parts have been mentioned previously and now compile! Thank you very much for your support! @SergioFormiggini