# Building 32 bit application with 64 bit development environment

Tags: c++, opencv, build, mingw

I am developing C++ code with OpenCV package for heterogeneous targets (windows/Mac/Linux - 32bit and 64 bit).

Libraries Required to build my c++:

1. MingW
2. OPenCV
   and Both are built for 64 bit.

I am able to generate 64 bit exe/dll/.so's on the 64 bit build environments.(Built opencv and mingw for 64 bit) and similarly for 32 bit.

Is it possible to create a 32 bit applications in 64 bit dev environment in windows with Mingw and OpenCV? A note here is that, **my supporting sdk's or libraries are built with 64 bit.**

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501878/force-gcc-to-compile-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-platform

Comment: why not just ask them on the forum? http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

Comment: Yes you can build 32bit exes using MingW/OpenCV, but no, you won't be able to do that without having a 32bit mingw toolset/standard library/SDK and building both OpenCV and your app with it. I'm not sure this answers your question though :]

Comment: @stiji So you mean to say, all the supporting packages ( Mingw and Opencv) have to built for 32 bit

Comment: Indeed. The code generated by compilers for 32bit/64bit targets is not compatible. Simplified example: a pointer in 32bit code is usually 4 bytes, but it is 8 bytes in 64bit code. You cannot expect that to be simply compatible.

Comment: 1.Is there any possibility to build the supporting packages (Mingw and OpenCV) to make it work with both 64 bit and 32 bit environment. 2. Can i just build the libraries with another 32 bit machine and point them in 64 bit dev or build environment ?

Comment: You seem to have some misunderstanding about 32/64bit but I cannot pinpoint what exactly from your questions. *You cannot mix 32/64bit builds/static libraries/dlls/executables/...*. Just like you usually cannot mix debug and release builds. You have to build everything seperately. And you can do that on a 64bit machine, see linked question from Sergay.

Comment: Sorry for asking question in a confusable way. 1. Think that the supporting package (Mingw and Opencv) have been built for 32 bit. 2. And i copy /paste them in 64 bit machine 3. Now in, 64 bit build environment, will it work, if i just point the 32 bit libs instead of 64 bit libs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71231/discussion-between-2vision2-and-stijn).

Answer (score 0):

In Win64 targetting Win32 you can do that by installing the correct mingw package from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/).

Note the "**Toolchains targetting Win32**".

For example, for 4.9.2 you can take [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-posix/dwarf/i686-4.9.2-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2.7z/download).  (I know as a fact that it works for OpenCV)

In the comments you got you can find also a solution for Linux64 targeting Linux32.