# how to install 32 bit tcl on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tcl, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried installing `tcl:i386` package but it still installs 64 bit package only. This I have verified by doing `parray tcl_platform`

If not via `apt-get` then is there a way I could download the source code and install from there (Other than active state packages)

Comment: Why would you need 32 bit tcl? The language behaves the same. Do you have a C compiled extension that isn't available on 64bit tcl?

Comment: We have certain spirent libraries of which only works with 32bit interpreter

Comment: Maybe building Tcl from source is the right approach; 32-bit platforms are still supported (except perhaps for when running OSX). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501878/force-gcc-to-compile-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-platform