# Compile git for 32-bit linux on shared hosting

Tags: linux, git, compilation, 32-bit

I need to set up the Git client on a cheap shared hosting, with a no-name 32-bit Linux distribution. GCC isn't available so I can't compile it on the server. I do have at my disposal 2 other 64-bit Linux servers and an OSX laptop which I could try to cross-compile a binary on. But I can't seem to get it to compile correctly; when I push the binaries to the 32-bit server it says it can't run the executable. It looks from other sources like I need to add "-arch i386" and/or "-m32" to the ./configure or make commands to work for 32-bit, but I guess I'm not using them correctly. Anyone know how to do this, or alternately, where to find  a universal 32-bit Git binary?

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason to compile it yourself and not just download some binary package?

Comment: You should check if the host provider mounted your home directory with the noexec option. When this is the case, you can't run any binary program from there.

Comment: @Sven Marnach But where can I download a Linux 64 bit git binary?

Comment: @Viktor: There is one in any major Linux distribution, just as an example.

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet is trying to compile git as a static binary. Your binary probably have different shared libraries versions (or even, not all dependencies installed).

This link:

[How to build git for a host with no compiler](http://www.lyraphase.com/wp/uncategorized/how-to-build-git-for-a-host-with-no-compiler/)

Provides information on how to build git as a static binary.

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake/1272408#1272408) provides information on how to cross compile it from a 64 bit host.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if it were me, I would just fire up 32-bit Linux in a VM and compile there.

Answer (score 1):

OS X isn't going to work - its geared to produce Mach-O binaries with the OS X syscall interface, not Linux ELF binaries.

Using -m32 on the CLFAGS is going to help, but most importantly, use -static as well. Static binaries are much more portable.

If that fails, please provide exactly how it failed.