# compile or download a static version of git

Tags: git, static

I need to have a running git version on a 32bit ubuntu machine, where I don't have root permissions. 
The PC is in a class room and I don't have root permissions to install e.g. curl.

For darcs the step is trivial, as I can download a static binary right from the website:
http://teratorn.org/code/darcs-2.8.0-linux-ghc7.0.4-CURL-packed.by.ermine.tar.bz2

I followed the instructions given in a previous question: [compile-git-for-32-bit-linux-on-shared-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147730/compile-git-for-32-bit-linux-on-shared-hosting)

I used the following command from a previouse post to configure the build:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/stephan/git-static CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}
-static -m32"
```

However, this leads to the following error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/stephan/Downloads/git-1.7.12.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Is there really no website where I can download a static git binary for 32 bit systems?

Do I have to install a 32 bit ubuntu in a VM?

Comment: either there's no c compiler, or there's no linker.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Running "./configure" and "make install" works without problems. So it has to be the CFLAGS I added, I guess.

Comment: You probably do not want a newline in CFLAGS.  Try: `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -static -m32"` with no newline.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I didn't have a newline on the console, I just checked again with no newline and the error is still the same. I guess the new line is from copy and paste from my console to the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed a quick solution and therefore I simply used darcs.

The static binaries of darcs are about 26mb big, they are very portable and are excellent for older systems. I got quickly used to the darcs commands, although I first though that this would take more time.

SmartGit could also help, but I think the whole client it is not open source. Further, I needed a console client for a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard to statically compile a copy of `Git` yourself, you can follow these instructions. I used a Musl cross compiler so the resulting binaries are completely static; they don't even link with glibc (which is a huge pain to deal with). It's not perfect though (see below):

```
# Download git and a musl compiler so that we don't depend on shitty glibc.

wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.31.1.tar.gz
wget http://musl.cc/x86_64-linux-musl-cross.tgz

tar xvf git-2.31.1.tar.gz
tar xvf x86_64-linux-musl-cross.tgz

# Add the compiler to our path.
export PATH="$(pwd)/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin:$PATH"

cd git-2.31.1/

# Make output directory.
mkdir output

# Configure to use the musl compiler with static linking.
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -static"
./configure --build x86_64-linux-musl-cross --prefix="$(pwd)/output"

# Disable various dependencies to make it easier to compiler & link.
# Note that this means you can't use the https transport, you can still use
# ssh though. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile

make NO_OPENSSL=1 NO_CURL=1 NO_EXPAT=1 NO_GETTEXT=1 NO_PERL=1 NO_PYTHON=1 NO_TCLTK=1 -j8 install
```

Unfortunately Git started as a bunch of hacky shell scripts - and some parts are still shell scripts! So it compiles to a ton of separate binaries rather than a single one like you might expect from a well designed program, however it does work. You get an `output` directory like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── bin
│   ├── git
│   ├── git-cvsserver
│   ├── git-receive-pack
│   ├── git-shell
│   ├── git-upload-archive
│   └── git-upload-pack
├── libexec
│   └── git-core
│       ├── git
│       ├── git-add
│       ├── git-add--interactive
│       ├── git-am
│       ├── git-annotate
│       ├── git-apply
│       ├── git-archimport
│       ├── git-archive
│       ├── git-bisect
│       ├── git-bisect--helper
│       ├── git-blame
│       ├── git-branch
│       ├── git-bugreport
│       ├── git-bundle
│       ├── git-cat-file
│       ├── git-check-attr
│       ├── git-check-ignore
│       ├── git-check-mailmap
│       ├── git-checkout
│       ├── git-checkout-index
│       ├── git-check-ref-format
│       ├── git-cherry
│       ├── git-cherry-pick
│       ├── git-clean
│       ├── git-clone
│       ├── git-column
│       ├── git-commit
│       ├── git-commit-graph
│       ├── git-commit-tree
│       ├── git-config
│       ├── git-count-objects
│       ├── git-credential
│       ├── git-credential-cache
│       ├── git-credential-cache--daemon
│       ├── git-credential-store
│       ├── git-cvsexportcommit
│       ├── git-cvsimport
│       ├── git-cvsserver
│       ├── git-daemon
│       ├── git-describe
│       ├── git-diff
│       ├── git-diff-files
│       ├── git-diff-index
│       ├── git-difftool
│       ├── git-difftool--helper
│       ├── git-diff-tree
│       ├── git-env--helper
│       ├── git-fast-export
│       ├── git-fast-import
│       ├── git-fetch
│       ├── git-fetch-pack
│       ├── git-filter-branch
│       ├── git-fmt-merge-msg
│       ├── git-for-each-ref
│       ├── git-for-each-repo
│       ├── git-format-patch
│       ├── git-fsck
│       ├── git-fsck-objects
│       ├── git-gc
│       ├── git-get-tar-commit-id
│       ├── git-grep
│       ├── git-hash-object
│       ├── git-help
│       ├── git-http-backend
│       ├── git-imap-send
│       ├── git-index-pack
│       ├── git-init
│       ├── git-init-db
│       ├── git-instaweb
│       ├── git-interpret-trailers
│       ├── git-log
│       ├── git-ls-files
│       ├── git-ls-remote
│       ├── git-ls-tree
│       ├── git-mailinfo
│       ├── git-mailsplit
│       ├── git-maintenance
│       ├── git-merge
│       ├── git-merge-base
│       ├── git-merge-file
│       ├── git-merge-index
│       ├── git-merge-octopus
│       ├── git-merge-one-file
│       ├── git-merge-ours
│       ├── git-merge-recursive
│       ├── git-merge-resolve
│       ├── git-merge-subtree
│       ├── git-mergetool
│       ├── git-mergetool--lib
│       ├── git-merge-tree
│       ├── git-mktag
│       ├── git-mktree
│       ├── git-multi-pack-index
│       ├── git-mv
│       ├── git-name-rev
│       ├── git-notes
│       ├── git-p4
│       ├── git-pack-objects
│       ├── git-pack-redundant
│       ├── git-pack-refs
│       ├── git-patch-id
│       ├── git-prune
│       ├── git-prune-packed
│       ├── git-pull
│       ├── git-push
│       ├── git-quiltimport
│       ├── git-range-diff
│       ├── git-read-tree
│       ├── git-rebase
│       ├── git-rebase--preserve-merges
│       ├── git-receive-pack
│       ├── git-reflog
│       ├── git-remote
│       ├── git-remote-ext
│       ├── git-remote-fd
│       ├── git-repack
│       ├── git-replace
│       ├── git-request-pull
│       ├── git-rerere
│       ├── git-reset
│       ├── git-restore
│       ├── git-revert
│       ├── git-rev-list
│       ├── git-rev-parse
│       ├── git-rm
│       ├── git-send-email
│       ├── git-send-pack
│       ├── git-shell
│       ├── git-sh-i18n
│       ├── git-sh-i18n--envsubst
│       ├── git-shortlog
│       ├── git-show
│       ├── git-show-branch
│       ├── git-show-index
│       ├── git-show-ref
│       ├── git-sh-setup
│       ├── git-sparse-checkout
│       ├── git-stage
│       ├── git-stash
│       ├── git-status
│       ├── git-stripspace
│       ├── git-submodule
│       ├── git-submodule--helper
│       ├── git-svn
│       ├── git-switch
│       ├── git-symbolic-ref
│       ├── git-tag
│       ├── git-unpack-file
│       ├── git-unpack-objects
│       ├── git-update-index
│       ├── git-update-ref
│       ├── git-update-server-info
│       ├── git-upload-archive
│       ├── git-upload-pack
│       ├── git-var
│       ├── git-verify-commit
│       ├── git-verify-pack
│       ├── git-verify-tag
│       ├── git-web--browse
│       ├── git-whatchanged
│       ├── git-worktree
│       ├── git-write-tree
│       └── mergetools
│           ├── araxis
│           ├── bc
│           ├── codecompare
│           ├── deltawalker
│           ├── diffmerge
│           ├── diffuse
│           ├── ecmerge
│           ├── emerge
│           ├── examdiff
│           ├── guiffy
│           ├── gvimdiff
│           ├── kdiff3
│           ├── kompare
│           ├── meld
│           ├── nvimdiff
│           ├── opendiff
│           ├── p4merge
│           ├── smerge
│           ├── tkdiff
│           ├── tortoisemerge
│           ├── vimdiff
│           ├── winmerge
│           └── xxdiff
└── share
    └── git-core
        └── templates
            ├── branches
            ├── description
            ├── hooks
            │   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
            │   ├── commit-msg.sample
            │   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
            │   ├── post-update.sample
            │   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
            │   ├── pre-commit.sample
            │   ├── pre-merge-commit.sample
            │   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
            │   ├── pre-push.sample
            │   ├── pre-rebase.sample
            │   ├── pre-receive.sample
            │   ├── push-to-checkout.sample
            │   └── update.sample
            └── info
                └── exclude

10 directories, 206 files
```

Add the `bin` directory to your `PATH` and you should be good to go! There are two caveats:

1. We disabled OpenSSL and Curl and so on which means you can't use `https://` URLs - only `ssh://`.
2. If you move it anywhere, you get warnings about missing templates.

This is because it uses `autotools` (another big hack) and `autotools` pretty much refuses to acknowledge that people might want portable programs, so you have to install it to a compile-time fixed *absolute* path. Git uses that to locate the `templates` directory, so if you move the `output` directory anywhere else you start getting warnings like this:

```
warning: templates not found in /home/tim/local/git-2.31.1/output/share/git-core/templates
```

However for some reason all of the `git` commands themselves work fine - you can do `git init`, `git log` and so on and it somehow finds the `libexec/git_core` directory even if you move it.