# Building 32bit shared library on 64 bit Linux with cmake

Tags: c, gcc, x86, cmake, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to build 32bit shared library on 64bit system using cmake:

`CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32;CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32;CMAKE_LD_FLAGS=-m32 -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu;CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_C_FLAGS=-m32;CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS=-m32;CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu;CFLAGS=-m32;LDFLAGS=-m32;CXXFLAGS=-m32 cmake`

As you can see, I tried to add all variables I've found on stack overflow, but cmake is still adding 64bit libxml2 instead of 32 bit:

-- checking for module 'libxml-2.0'
--   found libxml-2.0, version 2.7.8
-- xmllint program not found. Install it if you want validate generated doc file.
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so

How to force cmake to use 32 bit version located at `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`?

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake

Comment: @Vertexwahn: Except the poster obviously did read it. They just have something wrong in the settings apparently.

Comment: There is no `CMAKE_LD_FLAGS`, the cmake variable is called `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`. It takes defaults from _environment_ variable `LDFLAGS` though. The semicolon-separated string you wrote is not a valid syntax for anything. And it contains mix of environment and cmake variables. Can you reproduce the exact commands you used?

Answer (score 0):

The variable is *not* called <strike>`CMAKE_LD_FLAGS`</strike>, it is called `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.