# Using 32bit .so file in a 64bit environment

Tags: linux, qt, x86, 64-bit, qt4

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and I am getting the following error while compiling a Qt project which needs a 32bit `.so` file.

> error: `skipping incompatible /opt/lib/libEposCmd.so when searching for -lEposCmd`

I want to compile this project with `-m32` option but I don't know where should I insert this option.

Comment: I changed linux-g++ to linux-g++-32, and add -m32 option to CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and LFLAGS in make file but The makefile automatically gets changed with every i386 replaced with x86-64. then i got /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/QtXmlPatterns.so when searching for -lQtXmlPatterns
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved through below instruction:

- installing g++-multilib, libstdc++.i386, libgcc.i386,
  glibc-devel.i386, gcc-c++-32bit
- edite make file and adjust below config:

  ```
  cc = add -m32
  CFLAGS = add -m32
  INCPATH = linux-g++-32
  LFLAGS = -m32 -w1, -o1
  LIBS = i386-linux-gnu
  ```
- make softlink of

  > ```
  > /usr/lib/i386-GNU-linux/libQtCore.so.4.1
  >                     libQtGui.....
  >                     libQtXmlPattern..
  >                     libQtXml.....
  > ```

  to lib .... .so.o then to lib .... .so make clean and compile

Answer (score 0):

Use string command to see the values inside the .so file . And check the values

for eg string  /opt/lib/libEposCmd.so