# Need to configure / make / compile etc libxml2 in 32 bit on a 64 bit redhat machine

Tags: libxml2

There's obviously something that I'm not doing but I can't see what it is.

I run (in a bash shell)

CFLAGS='-m32-bit' ./configure

And I get:
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

====

But I need to compile/configure, whatever, to generate 32bit.

How do I find out what the "legal" directives are to have the ./configure script use i686-***** instead of x86_64-*****  using gcc compiler

This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Try `CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 ./configure`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit linux machine with gcc/cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

I tried many, many options in the configuration script but none worked.

The answer was to install the 32bit client (as well as keep the 64bit client). This worked first time!  Don't know why the m32 option didn't work.